# XML sitemap rebuild links on cron run

Tags: 7, cron, xml-sitemap

I've installed [XML Sitemap](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjD0pug5MvHAhWKW44KHV03D0E&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fxmlsitemap&ei=rFTgVcPMJYq3uQTd7ryIBA&usg=AFQjCNH8EStk9KKG4enXW2Rzw5tEnOErow&sig2=We8DJBaXeHEeb6ZIQZJ6aA). I can manually rebuild the link in **/admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/rebuild**. Is there any way to automatically rebuild the links (e.g. when cron runs XML sitemap would rebuild the links) ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set frequency of sitemap you can change it on daily,weekly,monthly basis

[How add frequency in sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/change_frequency_option-1811692-27.patch)

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can do it by another way by adding to your cron server your settings.

Comment: Can you expand on how this is done?